# Pycharm debugger, does not debug

Tags: qt, debugging, tensorflow, pycharm, python-3.6

In my Pycharm IDE, under Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python debugger:
I enabled "Attached to subprocess automatically when debugging"
and I disabled all other option including "PyQt compatibility" option.
Also, I have uninstalled "Qt" and "PyQt".

And whenever I tried to debug, it flashes to debug mode for (~1/10 second). and disappears.

And, I have a lot of packages(library) under my environment. however, I was able to debug until yesterday.

[image: debugger]

Comment: Could you solve it? I guess I got a similar problem. Debugger stops at a breakpoint, everything seems fine, shows variables etc. And then after a second when you want to have a closer look, the variables and frame info disappears, just as shown in your screenshot.

Comment: @Michael, It's actually the problem with the libraries using "Qt" such as Matplotlib, speech_to_text etc. Either need to identify the libraries, uninstall or update, which would be tedious. And another option is to create another virtual environment (conda env) and run/debug in new environment.

Comment: Ugh, I guess I further stick with the console and `pytest --pdb`.